# JQuery-swap to another image on hover - Code swaps but to the first option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a question:

I have on my Site a navigation bar whit multiple images
I wanted them to swap so I used this [Code](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/fade-to-another-image-on-hover-using-jquery) I found, changed it a bit so that it would work for me, but for some reason the second time I go over the image it changes to the first one
Could someone help me please. 
Ps. Sorry for my english

HTML:

```
<ul class="noBullet">
 <li><a href="#home" data-rel="close"><img class="fadeim" src="themes/menu/home=1.png"/></a></li>
 <li><a href="#spon"><img class="fadeim" src="themes/menu/spon=1.png"/></a></li>
     </ul>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(function() {
          // Change the image of hoverable images
          var openPng = $('.fadeim').attr('src');
          var closedPng = openPng.replace("=1.png", "=2.png");
          $('.fadeim').hover(function() { 
                $(this).stop(true, true).fadeOut(200, function() {
                      $(this).attr('src', closedPng).fadeIn(200);
                });
          }, function() {
                $(this).stop(true, true).fadeOut(200, function() {
                      $(this).attr('src', openPng).fadeIn(200);         
                });
          });
    });
```

Comment: Wrap this piece of code inside a [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code might be of some help. Basically, you set the second image (the one that is supposed to appear on hover as a `data-*` attribute and on each mousein and mouseout event, the original image and the one stored in the `data-*` attribute switch places.

```
<img class="hoverfun" src="first.jpg" data-hoverimg="second.jpg"/>

$(function(){
   $('.hoverfun').on('mouseenter mouseout', function(){
       var original = $(this).attr('src');
       var replacement = $(this).data('hoverimg');
       $(this).attr('src', replacement).data('hoverimg', original);
   });
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work at all...
it changes the img but only in one direction and 2. it only works on the first one...
but thank you

Comment: ohh - sorry your right. I made a mistake. 
And thank you for helping me +1

Comment: Works great except not in IE8 :/